# How to show distance between two locations in recyclerview items?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have two classes `User` and `School` as follow:

`User: name, age, latitude, longitude`

`School: name, latitude, longitude, level, address, rating`

And I have an adapter for lists of schools that comes from server. Everything is OK but I don't know how
to show distance of user from school in each item of recyclerview. Because adapter is a list of Schools and inside the adapter I can't access to current user data. (Can I?)

I tried to access the distance TextView of RecyclerView Item model from fragment but couldn't find any reference for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a reference of `User` instance to your `RecyclerView.Adapter` derived class. Then inside in `onBindViewHolder` override you will have access to both `User` and `School` instances which will allow you to calculate distance.

To calculate distance you can use: Location.distanceBetween [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[])](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D))

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you provide some reference/doc/example for your last par?

Comment: to calculate distance you can use: Location.distanceBetween https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[])

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate model of CombinedData, you can evaluate address using for loop against the ids, you must have ids to create the new class

Comment: can you get into details? your answer is like a comment.